# Using line space and smoothing

Tags: python, numpy, smoothing

Im having trouble running my function for smoothing my line. I have three separate variables i am importing from my csv file and need to smooth a line. Use exponential smoothing to remove as much of the random and periodic noise as you can from the signals without losing the important characteristics of the underlying signals. Choose individual time constants for smoothing each of the separate signals. Present your results graphically.

Here is some of my code:

```
from numpy import *                    
from scipy.stats import norm      
import csv                      
from matplotlib.pyplot import *  
from IPython.core.pylabtools import figsize  
#figsize(14, 7)
myID = 20155265
fn = str(myID)+".csv"
fn

data = np.genfromtxt("20155265.csv", delimiter=',', skip_header = 1)

smth1 = data[:,1]
smth2 = data[:,2]
smth3 = data[:,3]

def expSmooth(t,T,tau):        # returns a smoothed version of T with time constant tau
    tau = 0.01
    t = np.linspace(0, 1, 10540, 2)  # time of measurement
    T = smth1
    Ts = T.copy()              # another vector for the smoothed data
    for i in range(1,len(Ts)): # here's where the actual smoothing happens
        dt = t[i]-t[i-1]
        w = min(dt/tau,1)
        Ts[i] = Ts[i-1] * (1-w) + T[i] * w
    return Ts                  # return the smoothed data
    
plot(t,T)
plot(t,Ts, label = 'Smoothed Data')
xlabel('X-axis')
ylabel('Y-axis')
legend()
```

I also get this error when i run it:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-97b29b6d5ee7> in <module>
     16     return Ts                  # return the smoothed data
     17 
---> 18 plot(t,T)
     19 plot(t,Ts, label = 'Smoothed Data')
     20 xlabel('X-axis')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in plot(scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   2759 @docstring.copy(Axes.plot)
   2760 def plot(*args, scalex=True, scaley=True, data=None, **kwargs):
-> 2761     return gca().plot(
   2762         *args, scalex=scalex, scaley=scaley, **({"data": data} if data
   2763         is not None else {}), **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1645         """
   1646         kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D)
-> 1647         lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1648         for line in lines:
   1649             self.add_line(line)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    214                 this += args[0],
    215                 args = args[1:]
--> 216             yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
    217 
    218     def get_next_color(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    340 
    341         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
--> 342             raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
    343                              f"have shapes {x.shape} and {y.shape}")
    344         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10000,) and (10540, 2)
```

File is here (sample):

````
0.000000000000000000e+00,1.987649568467855232e+01,1.502770732591550562e+01,9.796532651620051269e+00
3.000284656988328846e-04,2.032588413582576692e+01,1.481391678788685518e+01,9.838773733555921552e+00
6.000569313976657692e-04,2.013795291324559145e+01,1.488696952239413029e+01,1.019210385573444100e+01
9.000853970964985996e-04,1.964606529847883110e+01,1.509763246836727113e+01,9.999835670287511746e+00
1.200113862795331538e-03,1.958979211177121371e+01,1.504942038590157338e+01,1.001807556622187967e+01
1.500142328494164477e-03,2.013860595459548009e+01,1.491842308020370567e+01,1.002097110595789431e+01
1.800170794192997199e-03,1.998167239030997777e+01,1.499645533912064010e+01,9.980793149246499851e+00
2.100199259891830355e-03,1.969884339061692202e+01,1.513994939974103282e+01,1.009387635287656337e+01
2.400227725590663077e-03,2.034433013515393185e+01,1.499177629776954745e+01,1.015006458706236359e+01
2.700256191289495799e-03,2.020764923596562568e+01,1.506159825939071339e+01,9.951152223719963885e+00
3.000284656988328955e-03,2.018453199942792864e+01,1.502803223857966231e+01,9.954336954252600123e+00
3.300313122687161677e-03,1.986644455611485682e+01,1.500975760158698868e+01,1.011627342579141775e+01
3.600341588385994399e-03,2.037481855217002291e+01,1.480681519737734853e+01,1.010520076861238259e+01
3.900370054084827554e-03,2.034613903815154146e+01,1.512797772833010335e+01,9.928197322515870837e+00
4.200398519783660710e-03,2.029763103912693012e+01,1.490699641094429140e+01,9.878651383161761501e+00
4.500426985482493432e-03,2.023957114424099757e+01,1.501257438050702397e+01,1.007540085537949359e+01
4.800455451181326154e-03,2.079433775809863860e+01,1.521317735549064665e+01,9.950279667926240634e+00
5.100483916880158876e-03,2.052803575990732554e+01,1.509758248396236979e+01,9.891986590075967811e+00
5.400512382578991598e-03,2.015682499321863119e+01,1.508489022657818523e+01,9.955164448148114076e+00
5.700540848277825187e-03,2.011819909355674696e+01,1.501075380973703943e+01,1.015537374721878905e+01
6.000569313976657909e-03,2.010649295602275188e+01,1.505906652977147964e+01,9.939615832465094059e+00
6.300597779675490631e-03,2.029240277512916890e+01,1.528788294973895390e+01,9.931050203825693146e+00
6.600626245374323353e-03,2.018988672364908155e+01,1.514912941994663598e+01,1.001967172353933222e+01
6.900654711073156075e-03,2.022259285851694699e+01,1.535320632721861323e+01,1.003319994573799079e+01
7.200683176771988797e-03,1.943010811933178061e+01,1.527350809725071734e+01,1.001153381953393051e+01
7.500711642470822386e-03,1.995908124651828430e+01,1.543542279981245002e+01,1.002018300551928753e+01
7.800740108169655108e-03,1.983987933411555460e+01,1.516848407834020485e+01,1.010803502461462067e+01```
````